# Add environment variable to access from php script without reboot?

Tags: php, ubuntu, server, environment-variables, ubuntu-16.04

I need to access an environment variable in my php script. It's running on a remote server. I've added them to /etc/environment but I can't access them as the server needs a reboot.

They can be echoed when I run

```
source /etc/environment
```

so it's not a problem with the file.

But the php script isn't running as my user so it doesn't have those variables. Since it's a remote server I don't particularly want to reboot it, as I assume this would then pull in the new environment variables I wrote to /etc/environment.
I've seen I can use /etc/profile but that won't affect the apache user, which I assume is running the php scripts.

I've tried to run

```
echo exec('source /env/environment && echo $the_var');
```

but the variable still doesn't return.

Any ideas please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using environment variables in your PHP code? Are you sure PHP constants aren't enough? What you're trying to achieve is such a rarity I doubt it's even possible.

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible. Environment variables are not global. Each process gets its own copy of the env vars which it is then free to modify and provide to each child process it spawns. A child process cannot modify its parent's env vars.

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong solution? I've got a username and password I don't want to hard code into the php code, so I though I could keep it in environment variables on the server. Is this the wrong way to go about it?